# Redirect in new tab when href is not known prior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link and a function which listens and gets triggered when that link is clicked.

The problem is the link is unknown in advance. Therefore, in this function an ajax request is made to the server to retrieve it. There is a strict requirement that the link must only be generated if requested by the user, and cannot be generated before hand.

How do you then redirect the user in a new tab to that link?

**Rewording**

So assuming I have

```
<a href="unknown" target="_blank">My Link</a>
```

And there is an event handler that gets triggered on click.

I've tried several different approaches. The first time

```
$('a[href="unknown"]').click(function(ev) {
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/get_link", 
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) { 
      link = response.link

      //substitute href of a to the new link

  });
});
```

Realized that this didn't work because ajax is asynchronous so the user will get redirected to unknown first. Then when the response is received the href will be substituted with the correct link.

So then I tried making ajax async:false, but still that didn't work and I wasn't comfortable locking the browser.

Lastly, I tried suppressing the default behaviour, and then opened a new window (but I was unable to open a new tab using jquery).

```
$('a[href="unknown"]').click(function(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/get_link", 
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) { 
      link = response.link

      //substitute href of a to the new link
      window.open(link)


  });
});
```

Apparently, after googling around you can't open a new tab in jquery because it is based on the user's browser settings.

How do you then redirect the user in a new tab when they click a link (unknown in advance) which triggers a javascript function that retrieves the link using an ajax request?

Comment: Can you possibly reword your question? It's very difficult to understand what you want because the question (the last sentence/paragraph) doesn't appear to be related to the rest of what you said. To cause a link to open in a new tab, try using the attribute `target="_blank"` within the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Can you be more specific, perhaps rephrase your question? I do not follow it correctly i believe.

Comment: I've reworded it, hopefully its clearer now. Thanks1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this server-side - send the user to a known URL, which then redirects them (HTTP 303) to the proper URL.

Comment: This was the solution I had opted for at first.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make your ajax synchronous:

```
$('a[href="unknown"]').click(function(ev) {
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/get_link", 
      context: document.body,
      async: false
    }).done(function(response) { 
      link = response.link

      //substitute href of a to the new link

  });
});
```

It appears that setting is deprecated, and I'm not sure what the alternative is supposed to be, but for now it works.

Comment: I tried this as described in the question, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution was making this a two step process. I added a button, when clicked would perform an ajax request, get the desired link, then using some javascript would present new links with the desired destination in a new tab.